# reading hex value from .txt file and storing it into unsigned char array[ ]

Tags: c, arrays

I have a `txt` file, content of file is :

`0x1a,0x2b,0xff,0x99,0x55`

I need to store all this value into :

> > unsigned char tempArray[10]={0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd,0xee,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}.

is there any solution so that my :

> > tempArray[]= {0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd,0xee,0x1a,0x2b,0xff,0x99,0x55}.

need to store values from .text file into specific location of array USING [c](/questions/tagged/c)/[cpp](/questions/tagged/cpp) only.

Thanking you in anticipation of favorable replies. :)

**EDIT**

'till now i am reading `1.txt` file character by character. variable `ch` store the the curent value, i am trying to store the `ch` value to `ch2*` later copy to array.

Te code below works fine for reading value but shows `segmentation fault` when `ch2` came in picture.

```
unsigned char tempArray[10]={0xaa,0xbb,0xcc,0xdd,0xee,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};

int main()
{
    char ch,i=0;

    FILE *fp;

    char *ch2=NULL;

    fp = fopen("1.txt","r"); // read mode

    if( fp == NULL )
    {
        printf("err");

        return 0;
    }

    printf("The contents of file are :\n");

    while(( ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
    {
        if(ch==',')
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c",ch);

            //sprintf(ch2,"%c",ch2);

            //printf("\tch2 :: %s",ch2);
        }

    }

    i++;

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what have tried so far to accomplish this?

Comment: Read an integer, store in array (why not a vector?), read possible comma, repeat.

Comment: Please, provide code of what you have tried so far

Comment: 1) There is no language C/C++. That looks like C code, if you compile as C++, change the tag. 2) removed the other unrelated tags. **Don't spam tags!**

Comment: 3) `fgetc` returns an `int` intentionally!

Comment: hello all, please pardon me for not following rules of portal as i am very new here. kindly request you help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code you can simply code:

```
uint32_t index = 0;

while(( ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
{
    if(ch==',')
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c",ch);

        tempArray[index] = ch;

        if ( tempArray < (sizeof(tempArray)/sizeof(tempArray[0])) )
        {
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

The segmentation fault you are seeing, I guess, is caused by

```
char *ch2=NULL;
```

After that you must allocate space where byte read will be placed. You can use `malloc` to do that.

```
char *ch2=malloc(size_of_you_buffer*sizeof(unsigned char);
```

Where `size_of_you_buffer` must be set accordingly to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char tempArray[]=
{
#include "file.txt"
};
```